# C# Entity Framework querying

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to C# and have problem I would usually solve with a subquery, but unsure how to go about it here.

I have a table called `Orders` that *has many* `OrderLines` (the foreign key is on the `OrderLines`).

The `OrderLines` have a lot of data, but I'm only interested in the sum of all `OrderLines.value` for each `Order`.

In pseudocode I want something like

```
DbSet.(o:order => o)
     .Include(o => Sum(o.OrderLines.value)
```

What is the idiomatic way to do something like this?

Comment: `DbSet.Select(o=> new OrderWitSum { /* initialize all fields like Field = o.Field */, Sum = o.OrderLines.Sum(l=>l.value) } )`

Comment: you may also create class `OrderWithSum` in such way `OrderWithSum  { Order Order; decimal Sum; }` then you can use `new OrderWithSum { Order = o, Sum = /*same code as above*/}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var ordersWithLineTotal = db.Set<Order>()
                            .Select(o => new { Order = o, LineTotal = o.OrderLines.Sum(l => l.LineTotal) })
                            .ToList();
```